# Bootstrap перестраивание под планшеты и мобильные устройства колонок

Tags: css, bootstrap

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите пожалуйста как расставить правильно, в нужные места bootstrap классы, что б получить для размеров -sm -xs две колонки, по 5 и 4 изображений в каждой. Как на фото.
А при -md и -lg, должно быть как изначально задано 3 колонки по 4 фото - Пример

```css
.wrapen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00f;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="wrapen">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 visible-md visible-lg">
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img1" /></div>
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img2" /></div>
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img3" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 visible-md visible-lg">
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img3" /></div>
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img4" /></div>
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img5" /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 visible-md visible-lg">
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img6" /></div>
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img7" /></div>
            <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img8" /></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не могу понять как работать когда изображений не чётное количество
[image: Рисунок колонки]

Comment: Блок с картинками <div class="block"> не нужен, сетка bootstrap в принципе не сложная, что бы так расставить, надо:
col-sm-6 col-xs-6 (то есть по половине экрана на одну группу картинок), не совсем понятно какого эффекта вы хотите добиться? Что бы был синий фон по краям, то padding:2px - в помощь. А если не четное что должно происходить по вашей логике?

Comment: Ваш комментарий ни чего не прояснил. Был дан пример с подключенной библиотекой(Bootstrap), и поставлен вопрос - как оптимизировать верстку под устройства с маленьким разрешением по заданной картинки.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно каждую картинку обернуть в col-..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img1" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img2" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img3" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img4" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img5" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img6" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img7" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img8" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="block"><img src="" alt="img9" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Тогда картинки автоматом будут выстраиваться в 3 колонки на больших экранах и в 2 на маленьких.

UPD: В этой /bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css вообще не видно классов для xs разрешения. Из-за этого не работает сетка col-xs-6 и изображения выстраиваются в одну колонку. Можно или использовать стабильную версию 3 или самостоятельно добавить классы xs, взяв их из 3 бутстрапа.

Comment: совет не работает http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWoRyq

Comment: Вижу, что на xs- почему-то получается 1 колонка. В остальном вроде все верно. Сейчас с xs разберусь..

Comment: Это сильно похоже на глюк альфы бутстрапа 4. С 3-м бутстрапом все работает как надо. Попробуйте подключить его <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Блин, сначала обрадовался что оно собирается. Потом убедился что и при разрешении <970px оно уже схлопывается в две колонки. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWEzoj  Короче снова не то

Comment: Так вы в своем вопросе и писали, что надо для sm и xs 2 колонки. При ширине <992 это уже sm. Уточните тогда вопрос, что вы все-таки хотите получить.

Comment: Согласен, мой косяк. Хочу что б на устройствах ДО 970px было две колонки, а на устройствах >970рх  три колонки.

Comment: ИМХО, если вам нужны не стандартные для бутстрапа точки перехода, то придется от него отказаться и делать свои переходы самостоятельно. Или перекрыть классы бутстрапа..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй это https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/dNBYLO

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="block-inner">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  ........................

</div>
```